# Multivariate division algorithm in sage

Tags: division, sage, polynomials

```
 Input: f_1, ..., f_s, f
 Output: a_1,...,a_s,r
  a_1:= 0; ...; a_s := 0; r := 0 
  p=f
 WHILE p! = 0 DO 
       i := 1 
       divisionoccurred := false 
 WHILE i <=s AND divisionoccurred = false DO 
       IF LT(f_i) divides lt(p) THEN 
           a_i:= a_i+lt(p)/lt(f_i) 
           p:= p - (LT(p)/LT(f_i))f_i, 
  divisionoccurred := true 
      ELSE i:= i + 1 
     IF divisionoccurred := false THEN 
          r := r + LT(p) 
          p := p - LT(p)
```

This is a multivariate division algorithm and I wanted to code this in sage.

The problem is that I am not sure what to write as the while loop condition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not post images, instead post in code blocks, it will help to debug the questions.

Comment: @Anand it's done would you be going through it?

Comment: I am having a problem in doing LT(p) by LT(f_i).I want to check whether the reminder is 0 after this division. Is there a code for this?